# How do i access an instance variable of a mutable array in another class

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class, variables, instance

I have researched this a lot.  I am new to objective c and just can't figure this out. 
If I have a class called MyClassA and a class called MyClassB. And I have an NSMutableArray *myArray and I alloc and init with initWithName:myArrayName in MyClassA.  How do I access or use myArrayName in MyClassB?

So What I have done is under MyClassB @implementation { MyClassA *myArrayPointer } and then I access it with myArrayPointer.myArrayName.  This compiles but doesn't print myArrayName. This is all pseudocode, if my actual code will help someone answer the question, I will submit that.  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste some more code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the `myArrayName` value to MyClassB, so declare one string variable inside MyClassB and then create the instance of MyClassB and set the variable value of MyClassA to the MyClassB like that below:-

MyClassB.h

```
@propery(nonAtomic,strong)NSString *name;
```

MyClassB.m

```
-(void)someMethod{
NSLog(@"%@",self.name);
}
```

MyClassA.m

```
-(void)someMethod{
MyClassB *clsB=[MyClassB alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourXib"];
clsB.name=myArrayName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it.  The below assumes both MyClassA and MyClassB will both be instantiated in applicationWillFinishLaunching

in AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "MyClassA.h"
#import "MyClassB.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>
{
    MyClassA *myClassA;
    MyClassB *myClassB;
}
```

in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    myClassA = [[MyClassA alloc] init];
    myClassB = [[MyClassB alloc] initWithClassA:myClassA];
}
```

In MyClassA.h:

```
@interface MyClassA : NSObject

{
    @public

    NSMutableArray *myArray; // Array will be alloc inited in the init method of MyClassA.m file
}
```

in MyClassB.h:

```
#import "MyClassA.h"

@interface MyClassB : NSObject

{
    MyClassA *myClassA; // myClassA will be set in the initWithClassA method
}

- (id) initWithClassA:(MyClassA *)classa;
```

in MyClassB.m:

```
- (id) initWithClassA:(MyClassA *)classa
{
    self = [super init];

    myClassA = classa;

    return self;
}
```

myArray (instantiated in myClassA) can now be accessed from myClassB with myClassA->myArray